# Python selenium: running into StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape all job postings for the last 24 hours from Glassdoor and save them to a dictionary.

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('path_to_firebox_binary.exe')
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, capabilities=cap, executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

base_url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?suggestCount=0&suggestChosen=false&clickSource=searchBtn' \
       '&typedKeyword=data+sc&sc.keyword=data+scientist&locT=C&locId=1154532&jobType= '
driver.get(url=base_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#filter_fromAge>span"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
        By.XPATH, "//div[@id='PrimaryDropdown']/ul//li//span[@class='label' and contains(., 'Last Day')]"))).click()

# find job listing elements on web page
listings = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jl")
n_listings = len(listings)

results = {}

for index in range(n_listings):
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jl")[index].click()  # runs into error
    print("clicked listing {}".format(index + 1))
    info = driver.find_element_by_class_name("empInfo.newDetails")
    emp = info.find_element_by_class_name("employerName")

results[index] = {'title': title, 'company': emp_name, 'description': description}
```

I keep running into the error message

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message:
> The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the
> DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been
> refreshed

for the first line inside my `for` loop. Even if the for loop runs for some number of times, it eventually leads to the exception showing up. I am new to selenium and web scraping, will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time a new post is selected the clicked element is being modified, and therefor the DOM is being refreshed. The change is slow, certainly in comparison to the actions in the loop, so what you want to do is to slow it a little bit. Instead of using fixed sleep you can wait for the changes to occur

Every time you select a posting a new class `selected` is being added and the `style` attribute lose it's content. You should wait for this to happen, get the information, and click the next post

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
for index in range(n_listings - 1):
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.selected:not([style="border-bottom:0"])')))
    print("clicked listing {}".format(index + 1))
    info = driver.find_element_by_class_name('empInfo.newDetails')
    emp = info.find_element_by_class_name('employerName')
    if index < n_listings - 1:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.selected + .jl').click()
```

Comment: What is the last `if` statement doing here?

Comment: @VisheshShrivastav we are looking for the next post every time, but when the last post is selected there isn't next post, the `if` is to prevent the search when the last post is selected.

Answer (score 1):

This error means the element you are trying to click on was not found, you have to first make sure the target element exists and then call `click()` or wrap it in a try/except block.

```py
# ...
results = {}

for index in range(n_listings):
    try:
        driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jl")[index].click()  # runs into error
    except:
        print('Listing not found, retrying in 1 seconds ...')
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
    print("clicked listing {}".format(index + 1))
    info = driver.find_element_by_class_name("empInfo.newDetails")
    emp = info.find_element_by_class_name("employerName")
# ...
```